# drawing line selection issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

Hope you are all having a wonderful day..

so here's a thing i made a and online app with fabricjs and pdfjs " almost done", but i'm having some issues while drawing lines..
i'm using the latest version of FabricJS (5.2.1)

when i draw a line it will usefully draw with no issues, but when i try to select the draw line button an move the cursor around the canvas the previous drawing line stars following the cursor!!
can anyone help me with this issue?

Also below there's further info about the app link, Line Drawing code, error and what i wanted to be

My issue: https://gfycat.com/harshspotlesscollie

This is what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/vmachan/L10ren1q/

Draw Line Code (Found in viewer.js file: line 110):

```
$(".tool-button").on("click", function () {
      $(".tool-button").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      const addLine = () => {
        if ($("#addLine").hasClass("active")) {
          mode="draw";
          isDown = true;
          canvas.on("mouse:down", function (o) {
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
            var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
            line = new fabric.Line(points, {
              strokeWidth: 5,
              fill: 'black',
              stroke: 'black',
              originX: 'center',
              originY: 'center',
              ObjectId: "id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
            });
            canvas.add(line);
            canvas.renderAll();
          });
          canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
            if (!isDown) return;
            if(mode=="draw"){
              var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
              line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
              canvas.renderAll(); 
            }
          });
          
          canvas.on('mouse:up', function(){
            $(".tool-button").removeClass("active");
            isDown = false;
            canvas.selection=false;
          });
      };
      addLine();
    });
```

Comment: 1. So that minus button you click that causes a line to be drawn... its `<a>` tag has an id of `addLine`, not `addText` or an id of the like. I am assuming that its actual intent was to do so, because the pop up text is "Add Text". 2. The thing thats interesting about the bug is that I don't believe that it is specific to fabricjs, rather that its a bug in your code. The code `line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });` is telling me from the best I can gauge that `line` is actually undefined, and that's why the line isn't sticking to the end point.

Comment: My best guess is that mode isn't being updated on a global scale. I am assuming that mode is intended to be used as a global variable and it isn't being used that way.

Comment: @shmack thank you very much, this fixed my problem you are a hero..

Comment: just one more thing i'm having a major issue while changing the screen size the canvas object doesn't scale or stay on the same position, is there anyway to fix this in your opinion?

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about... I actually just dealt with this problem like 6 months ago. For page resizing, you need an event listener on the `window` object. Inside of it the event listener, I dont believe there is actually a way to track the page increase or decrease, so you will have to define a global variable tracking whichever is going to be the biggest (either the width or the height of the page) and store the current width in there. When the window resizes (detected by the event listener) you can use an anonymous function to determine the page increase or decrease.

Comment: And by what percentage the page increased or decreased by. Then you need to 1: draw a rectangle on fabric as big as your current canvas from the top left corner, to the bottom right. 2: select all the elements (including the rectangle). 3: resize the physical html canvas using css or javascript to fit the actual dimensions of the page according to the window increase. 4: tell fabric what the new size of the canvas is going to be (take the percentage increase or decrease that you got from the window and apply it to fabric like so `canvas.setWidth(canvas.getHeight * pageDelta))`. 5: scale the

Comment: selected fabric item (the box with all the other stuff) from the group and center it. 6: get the box and delete it. If you can open another question and send me the link, maybe I can post an answer there for this concept.

Comment: fabric also rounds points to a default precision, so if you use this method and the objects are noticeably misplaced or whatever, you will have to set the fabric rounding precision to be more precise.

Comment: @shmack thank you very much, i will open a new question tomorrow and share the whole information about it, including a gif of the issue, and the code, i'll try to tag you if there's a feature in stack overflow for tagging!

Comment: @Shmack here's the issue i'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425190/fabricjs-responsive-canvas-items-issues