# Fabricjs responsive canvas items issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs, pdf.js

i'm having some issues when the canvas width and height changes, i want the items to be in there same position..

i' using the latest version of fabricjs and using pdfjs library with it..

here's the code i'm using to try to fix it, but not working unfortunately:

```
function rescale_canvas_if_needed() {
  var optimal_dimensions = [$(".canvasWrapper").outerWidth(), $(".canvasWrapper").outerHeight()];
  var scaleFactorX = window.innerWidth / optimal_dimensions[0];
  var scaleFactorY = window.innerHeight / optimal_dimensions[1];
  if (scaleFactorX < scaleFactorY && scaleFactorX < 1) {
    canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] * scaleFactorX);
    canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] * scaleFactorX);
    canvas.setZoom(scaleFactorX);
  } else if (scaleFactorX > scaleFactorY && scaleFactorY < 1) {
    canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] * scaleFactorY);
    canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] * scaleFactorY);
    canvas.setZoom(scaleFactorY);
  } else {
    canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0]);
    canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1]);
    canvas.setZoom(1);
  }

  canvas.calcOffset();
  canvas.renderAll();
}


function handle_resize() {
  $(".canvas-container").hide();
  rescale_canvas_if_needed();
  $(".canvas-container").show();

}
```

to test it: try adding an drawing on the book and click on the zoom in and out and see how the canvas items position is changing.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the assumption that you've calculated the scale factor correctly - I'd either have to think really critically about the scaleFactorX and scaleFactorY idea or just play with code (of which I am too lazy to do at this moment), but you may only need to check for 1 of them for scaling:

```
function rescale_canvas_if_needed() {
  var optimal_dimensions = [$(".canvasWrapper").outerWidth(), $(".canvasWrapper").outerHeight()];

  // add a rectangle the size of the current canvas and center it
  rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height,
    angle: 0,
    fill: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    transparentCorners: true
    });
  canvas.add(rect);
  rect.center();

  // get an active selection of all objects

  canvas.discardActiveObject();
  var sel = new fabric.ActiveSelection(canvas.getObjects(), {canvas: canvas});
  canvas.setActiveObject(sel);
  canvas.requestRenderAll();

  // scale your canvas

  var scaleFactorX = window.innerWidth / optimal_dimensions[0];
  var scaleFactorY = window.innerHeight / optimal_dimensions[1];
  if (scaleFactorX < scaleFactorY && scaleFactorX < 1) {
    canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] * scaleFactorX);
    canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] * scaleFactorX);
    canvas.setZoom(scaleFactorX);
  } else if (scaleFactorX > scaleFactorY && scaleFactorY < 1) {
    canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] * scaleFactorY);
    canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] * scaleFactorY);
    canvas.setZoom(scaleFactorY);
  } else {
    canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0]);
    canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1]);
    canvas.setZoom(1);
  }
  canvas.calcOffset();

  // scale the active selection to the new width

  sel.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);

  // center the selection

  sel.center();

  // deselect the active selection

  canvas.discardActiveObject();

  // delete the rectangle

  canvas.remove(rect);

  canvas.requestRenderAll();
}


function handle_resize() {
  // I don't think you should have to hide or show the canvas-container
  $(".canvas-container").hide();
  rescale_canvas_if_needed();
  $(".canvas-container").show();

}
```

This will discard any active selections on the page before resizing it - maybe thats how you will want it, but you could get the active selection before resizing everything, then once it is done with all the resizing, reselect that active selection.

Warning: I didn't test this, so it may have a bug, invalid syntax, or other problems within that nature.

Let me know if you can't past another hurtle, given this bit of code.

Comment: alright, a small update: it's kinda not working, i have added your code but no luck! also i have updated the provided link, so kindly check the page and there's a file called "viewer.js", please check the "canvasFArea" function inside it to see your code

Comment: also please note again try click the pen in the menu and try drawing anything then click on zoom in or zoom out and you will see the canvas item position is changing :(

Comment: and please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong!

Comment: Sure thing @WhiteWolf . I am just having a hard time seeing the problem. From my end it looks like everything is scaling properly in terms of objects. I just don't know if you are intending for your html canvas elements to be a set size or not, I guess.

Comment: If you're not doing a hard refresh on your your page when you update your javascript, you should (ctrl + shift + r). It could also be me.

Comment: Ah hah! What function do you use to scale the page, i.e. when I click the magnifying glass?

Comment: @WhiteWolf I should've tagged you in my previous comment. I think you need to attach the above code to your scaling code for the magnifying glass'.

Comment: sorry for being late to reply!, ill me checking the scaling code when i click. bcuz it's made by pdf.js (inside the viewer.js), i hope i solve this issue asap :(

Comment: Yah. I would attach the above code to your zoom functions attached to the magnifying glasses.

Comment: @WhiteWolf if this is the correct answer, could you mark it as so?

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue unfortunately! 

Comment: Really? Even with the code snippet?